# Проблема с jQuery в IE11

Tags: javascript

Не работает следующий код в `IE11`, а так же если повесить событие через `onclick`. При этом в `chrome` работает. В чём может быть проблема?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Player</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="launch btn btn-primary">Запустить</button>
 </div>
 <script>
  $(".launch").click(function(){
   alert("TEST");
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Все прекрастно работает, возможно у вас заблокированы всплывающие окна в IE, не смотрели что показывает консоль?

Comment: @WanSpi, IE пишет обычно , что заблокировал всплывающее окно

Comment: тогда это проблема Вашего браузера, просто в настройках уберите галочу "Блокировать всплывающие окна по умолчанию" и все ок, только вопрос надо ли это делать?

Comment: Добавлю от себя, если браузер что то блокирует, значит он так решил, и к сожелению, или к счастью, разработчик страницы с этим ничего не поделает, разве что вместо Alert, можете создать похожее окно на самой странице, тогда оно не будет заблокированно, да и оформить его сможете красиво.

Comment: @WanSpi, не помогло. Проблема в том, что вместо alert должен быть вызов функии, которая уже может перебросить пользователя на другую страницу. Код это пример, того что не работает

Comment: А какая ошибка то показывается в консоле ?

Comment: @WanSpi, The attached page targets document mode 7. Some console APIs and features may not be available